# ng-repeat needs to loop over child object of $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been led to believe that it's better to use a child object on a scope rather than adding straight to the scope... e.g.

```
$scope.model.mystuff
```

is better than

```
$scope.mystuff
```

However, my first very simple bit of code using ne-repeat works when you do this...

```
$scope.myStuff = [{},{},{}]

<div ng-repeat="things in myStuff">Test</div>
```

If I run that I see the word Test 3 times. If I do the following though...

```
$scope.model.myStuff = [{},{},{}]

<div ng-repeat="things in model.myStuff">Test</div>
```

Then it doesn't loop at all. I'm sure I've just misunderstood this and the solution is very simle.

Comment: You don't really need a child object as much as you need an array of objects (not an array of primitives) when using ng-repeat.  Seee [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482) -- look for the bolded "ng-repeat" section -- if you want the full story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, if you provide a jsfiddle, it might make things easier :)

The problem seems to be how you declared

```
$scope.model.myStuff = [{},{},{}]
```

$scope.model didn't exist at that time, so I just quickly added it the line before like so:

```
$scope.model = {}
$scope.model.myStuff = [{},{},{}]
```

And then the ng-repeat worked, outputting test 3 times

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/rtCP3/33/